# Redux in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I'm having trouble with my Actions in Redux with my NextJS app.. I'd imagine it would be relatively similar to implementing Redux in any other React application but I can't for the life of me get my actions to fire off. It has been awhile since I've touched Redux so it might be something really obvious that I'm missing but I've spent several hours trying to troubleshoot it. When my window width gets to 600px I have a breakpoint that shows a hamburger icon and I want it to add the class "open" to my navbar. Here's my repo. https://github.com/nicer00ster/nicer00ster-blog

Answer (score 0):

add an `eventListener` to handle window resize and then check the `innerWidth` of `window`  to call your action.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { toggleMenu } from '../../actions'
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';

import Nicer00ster from '-!svg-react-loader?name=Nicer00ster!../../images/svg/nav/nicer00ster.svg';
import Smartphone from '-!svg-react-loader?name=Smartphone!../../images/svg/nav/smartphone.svg';
import House from '-!svg-react-loader?name=House!../../images/svg/nav/house.svg';
import Telephone from '-!svg-react-loader?name=Telephone!../../images/svg/nav/telephone.svg';


class Navbar exntends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onWindowResize = this.onWindowResize.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);
   }
   onWinodwResize() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 600 && !this.props.isOpen)
      this.props.toggleMenu();
    }
  render() {
   const {isOpen, toggleMenu} = this.props;
   return (
    <div>
      <div className={ isOpen ? "navbar open" : "navbar" }>
          <ul className="navbar__links">
            <li className="navbar__item">
              <Link to="/">
                <Nicer00ster className="logo" width={200} height={100}/>
              </Link>
              <Sidebar />
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul className="navbar__navigation">
            <li className="navbar__item" onClick={ toggleMenu }>
              <Link activeClassName="active" to="/">
                <a className="navbar__link">
                  <House className="navbar__item--svg" width={100} height={50} />
                  <span className="navbar__item--text">Home</span>
                </a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="navbar__item" onClick={ toggleMenu }>
              <Link activeClassName="active" to="/blog">
                <a className="navbar__link">
                  <Telephone className="navbar__item--svg" width={100} height={50} />
                  <span className="navbar__item--text">Blog</span>
                </a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="navbar__item" onClick={ toggleMenu }>
              <Link activeClassName="active" to="/work">
                <a className="navbar__link">
                  <Smartphone className="navbar__item--svg" width={100} height={50} />
                  <span className="navbar__item--text">Work</span>
                </a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="navbar__item" onClick={ toggleMenu }>
              <Link activeClassName="active" to="/contact">
                <a className="navbar__link">
                  <Telephone className="navbar__item--svg" width={100} height={50} />
                  <span className="navbar__item--text">Contact</span>
                </a>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <Sidebar isOpen={isOpen} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default connect(function(state) {
  return { isOpen: state.app.open }
}, { toggleMenu })(Navbar);
```